# Extracting JSON data into simple columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have inherited a table that contains a column which looks something like this:

```
field_a::json
=============
{'a':['1', '2']}
{'b':['foo', 'bar']}
{'a':[null, '3']}
```

Essentially, I want to convert this into something more usable in a view or similar.  There is only ever one key, and the data is always a two element array.  This is what I'm aiming for:

```
field|value1|value2
===================
a    |     1|     2
b    |   foo|   bar
c    |  null|     3
```

How might I query this given I don't know the name of any of the keys in play here?  This is on PG11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view that normalizes the data:

```
create view view_of_my_table as
select id, key::text, value->>0 as value1, value->>1 as value2
from my_table
cross join jsonb_each(field_a)

select *
from view_of_my_table

 id | key | value1 | value2 
----+-----+--------+--------
  1 | a   | 1      | 2
  2 | b   | foo    | bar
  3 | c   |        | 3
(3 rows)
```

Note that every select query on the view implies querying the source table with the function `jsonb_each()`, so this is not the most performant way. To improve performance, you can use a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) and refresh it after any insert/update of the source table.

Live demo in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b3a7d1bf1e2ce27ef1d7290fb3195b30)

Comment: +1. Change `->>` to `->`, and `COALESCE` to `'null'` (in case either of the array values aren't defined), and I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: I do not see any reason to use JSONB columns in the view. Also, `null::jsonb` is correctly converted to `null::text` in the view, so `coalesce()` is useless here.

Comment: 1) you're losing types by converting the values columns to text - why? 2) there's difference between `'null'::jsonb::text` and `null::jsonb::text` - unless you specifically want to differentiate between explicit `null` JSON value and an empty value, you need the coalesce.

Comment: Why? Because storing values of different types in a table column is against RDBMS rules and is a potential reason for further problems. Obviously, `"null"::jsonb` is converted to `'null'::text` while `null::jsonb` to `null::text`, both conversion are correct.

Comment: 1) JSON first-class datatype support, hello? If you're so strong-type-minded, then how can you haphazardly throw types out of the window by converting everything to strings? 2) I was arguing for consistency, not correctness. It's interesting you want to  throw away types in the first part, and in the second part split hairs about `null` (JSON) and `null` (postgres) types -- but I concede my point here, since it's better to not lose information as I stated in (1).

Comment: RDBMS are strong-type-minded, not me. `null::text` is a natural representation of `null::jsonb`, what can be done better here?

Answer (score 0):

Probably horribly inefficient, but it does the job:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS source_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE source_table ( field_a JSONB );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS target_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE target_table ( field TEXT, value1 JSONB, value2 JSONB );

INSERT INTO source_table VALUES
    ('{"a":["1", "2"]}'),   
    ('{"b":["foo", "bar"]}'),
    ('{"a":[null, 3]}');

INSERT INTO target_table
SELECT
    tmp.obj->>'key',
    COALESCE( TO_JSONB(((tmp.obj->'value')::JSONB)->0), 'null' ),
    COALESCE( TO_JSONB(((tmp.obj->'value')::JSONB)->1), 'null' )
FROM (
    SELECT TO_JSON(x) obj FROM (SELECT JSONB_EACH(field_a) x FROM source_table) AS x
) AS tmp;

SELECT * FROM target_table;
```

yields:

```
field|value1|value2
===================
"a" |   "1"|   "2"|
"b" | "foo"| "bar"|
"a" |  null|     3|
```

Where `value1` and `value2` are `JSONB` columns, and `null` is retained as `JSONB`.

Also, even though you specified that each object contains just a single key, the above solution will work regardless of how many keys it contains.

PosgreSQL 9.5+

Comment: Is there a way that's feasible via a view or something so I don't need to keep updating the table?

Comment: If by feasible you mean fast, then I didn't benchmark it so I don't really know how fast it is. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯